# KAFKA initial load from database

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm starting to play with kafka and there are a lot of questions in my head when importing data from a database.

MY scenario is: I have a relational database with a few tables and I want to import them into KAFKA topics. The confusion in my head is: if I use KAFKA connect to import all these tables, how will my consumers know when the data has **all** been loaded? Before my consumer starts working, i need most of the records from the different tables to be loaded into the kafka topics.

For example, I have a Customer and a Order table in my database. I want to import these 2 tables into a Customer and a Order topic. If my consumer starts because there is a new Order but the information about the customer is not yet present in the Customer topic, it will not work. Am I over-complicating this?

Comment: Is data actively being added to the tables while you would be importing it? How to queries currently know that all data is inserted into the database when they perform a query?

Comment: @cricket_007 the database is a staging area. Whenever there is new data, the staging should be updated. It should be on a batch basis though.

Comment: Have you considered changing your architecture to support CDC-based workloads?

Comment: Have you had a look at the confluent page here? I think it might be useful. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka provides a real time stream of events over time. Re. your question "how will my consumers know when the data has all been loaded" - you're asking about completion of some finite activity (loading data to Kafka?), but events occur and continue to occur over time. Your Streams application runs continually and continues to run - there is no 'end'.

Your current thinking about data in a table verses events in a Kafka Topic sounds like you're treating these as two equivalent concepts, but they are not.

Comment: You are right. Trying to compare a table to a event is not the correct way. I have to leave the transactional way of thinking and consider events as my data. My problem was that i thought that I needed all the data before i can start working (as I would in a orchestration) but I'm using an event driven solution and events are what i have to work with

Answer (score 1):

> if I use KAFKA connect to import all these tables, how will my consumers know when the data has all been loaded?

As other answers say, they wouldn't out of the box.

You would need to monitor the import process manually (or programmatically) or determine your initial conditions of "completeness", or at least at which you're confident in starting a consumer.

From there, I'd suggest either setting up CDC or make customers and orders services writing directly to Kafka topics. If you write to Kafka directly, you will need to consider idempotent events such as the ordering of new customer accounts, edits, and deletes. Then if customers are deleted, do you still keep all orders associated with that customer, for example?

Once both sources of data are in topics, you're welcome to join customer orders back together with KStreams / KSQL

> it will not work

You might want to clarify what "it" is, but the consumer from at least one topic will work fine. The join mentioned above will be eventually consistent while data is being imported, but that's the tradeoff you have by not having transactional, atomic semantics in asynchronous processing

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. I think my problem is that I'm still accustomed to the way an orchestration works. I am used to having a database transaction that inserts what I want in one go, but I have to shift my way of thinking. I have to think that this is event driven and updates and new data can always come later.

Comment: Yup. Event sourcing or using Distributed Sagas are ways to think through those issues

Answer (score 0):

**Technically**: you need synchronization mechanism for your producers and consumers. Kafka does not provide capability to let consumers know that "topic is full" (as there might always be someone writing to the topic).

Producers need to somehow (e.g. through another Kafka topic?) inform the consumers that "they have finished their phase". Only after the consumers have received that information, they can start their processing.

**Side comment**: You mentioned

```
If my consumer starts because there is a new Order but the information about the customer is not yet present in the Customer topic, it will not work
```

How are you solving this problem now?